# How to replace deprecated FSFileOperationCreate in 10.8?

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I'm writing code specific for MountainLion so I want to try to avoid to use deprecated APIs.

I use [FSFileOperationCreate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSFileOperationCreate) to receive information about copy progress (kFSOperationBytesCompleteKey, kFSOperationThroughputKey, kFSOperationTotalBytesKey) but documentation says

> Creates an object that represents an asynchronous file operation.
>   (Deprecated in OS X v10.8. At the Foundation layer, use
>   copyItemAtURL:toURL:error: instead. At the POSIX/BSD layer, use
>   copyfile(3) OS X Developer Tools Manual Page instead.)

Using copyItemAtURL:toURL:error and [NSFileManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSFileManagerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) seems impossible to obtain same informations.

How can I obtain same behaviour in 10.8 without rewriting code myself?

Does Apple know now it is simple awful to make same thing?

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to file a bug with Apple at [http://bugreporter.apple.com](http://bugreporter.apple.com).  Apple needs to know that there is useful information that developers need and won't be able to get at with the "officially supported" replacement API's.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the answer you wish to hear[1], but wrap `copyfile(3)` in your own Obj-C wrapper. You should be able to calculate all you need using the callbacks, in particular the progress one. HTH.

[1] Quite a few APIs in this general area have been deprecated, and while some new APIs have been introduced they seem incomplete. Reasonable guess might be more is coming in 10.9...